# get.symbols is returning "argument conn is missing, with no default"?

Tags: quantmod

> getSymbols("AAPL")
> Warning: AAPL download failed; trying again.
> Error in getSymbols.yahoo(Symbols = "AAPL", env = , verbose = FALSE,  :
> Unable to import “AAPL”.
> argument "conn" is missing, with no default

I also get this error as well:

btc <- getSymbols.yahoo("BTC-USD",)
Warning: BTC-USD download failed; trying again.
Warning: Unable to import “BTC-USD”.
argument "conn" is missing, with no default
Warning messages:
1: closing unused connection 4 (https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/BTC-USD?period1=1167609600&period2=1624406400&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=Forbidden)

I dont have this issue on my personal computer with Quantmod. I am at work using a VPN which could be the issue. Does anybody else have experience with this error?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact **same problem**, **here is how I solve it**:

instead of using getSymbols("AAPL") as you did; go to yahooo finance and search there for the exact name of the Apple ticker.
For example, in Brazil the ticker for Petrobras at Yahoo Finance is not PETR4, it is PETR4.SA. (https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/PETR4.SA?p=PETR4.SA&.tsrc=fin-srch)
It is required that you use the exact name.